# double Circular progress bar using ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

Circular Progress bar [Here is an image of the progress bar I want to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9XdJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use 2 library:

- Combine javascript and css (progressbar.js)

https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/

- Just css

https://www.digitaldesignjournal.com/best-circular-progress-bar-html-css/

Comment: Hi,
thanks for giving replay,
circle with in the circle type of plugins i need it pls send any other links